# Comparing dates in excel with diffrent formats

Tags: excel

I want to compare dates in an excel file. Below is the example of data.

```
Coloumn A     Coloumn B   Coloumn C
05.01.2018 (date in coloumn A)    05.01.2018 (date in coloumn B)   Formula (date in coloumn C) - If(A2=B2;"dates are same";"check")
```

dates in coloumn A is coming from other excel file and date in coloumn in B is coming from Business Object with vlookup. Both dates are in diffrent format, if I try to change the format its now working.

I already tried to change fromat with /or . and formatiing cells with special frormat, but it did not worked.

Can someone help to resolve this?

Thanks in advance.
BR,
Sai

Comment: looks like they are in the same format to me? May be try: `--A2=--B2`

Comment: If you are just comparing them and not displaying anywhere, use date values for comparison, without any formatting. Excel has them as integral number values that be easily compared.

Comment: I would bet that those imported date object are seen as TEXT. Try making a simple mathematics operation. Like if you select two dates, can they sum? Like shash pointed out, dates are just integer referring to Jan 0th 1900.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the details you provided, I think one of the dates is in Text format which is causing the error in comparison formula. You can delimit the date which is in Text format in 3 new columns, and then use Date function in another column which will return the data in date format.

Sharing the snips here.[Steps for delimit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOwaj.jpg)
[Using Date function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2BUH.jpg)